# How two people can commit in a particular PR

Tags: git, github

I have been contributing to an open source project for a while now, I know most of the `Git's Workflow`, but recently I founded an interesting thing
while I was looking at another contributor's `PR`, I saw two people's image on the `commit`, when I clicked on the commit it said

`xyz committed with abc`

What does that mean ? How can another person commit with another person in his `PR`, I found it a bit interesting and confusing, therefore thought to ask here.

Comment: Hope this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37245303/what-does-usera-committed-with-userb-13-days-ago-on-github-mean

Answer (score 0):

You're probably seeing an **author** and a **committer** on the commit. See [this for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755824/what-is-the-difference-between-author-and-committer-in-git)